# game center login form when player not authenticated sprite kit

Tags: ios, authentication, game-center

I created a class of NSObject and I have this authenticate function in it:

```
-(void)authenticateLocalUser {

if(!gameCenterAvailable) { return; }

GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
__weak GKLocalPlayer *blockLocalPlayer = localPlayer;

localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"authenticateHandler");
    if (viewController != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"viewController != nil");
    }
    else if (blockLocalPlayer.isAuthenticated)
    {
        NSLog(@"localPlayer already authenticated");
        //do some stuff
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"local player not authenticated");
        // not logged in
    }
};
```

}

Its the new version i looked up , but its not displaying the Game Center login form.

Im calling this method in my AppDelegate.m if you need this information.

I think I have to put something in there when the player is not logged in like get the login form. But I don't know how.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: which of your NSLog statements are being printed?

Comment: well if im logged in to game center-> player is authenticated, if not the other one. They are both displayed correctly, I just want if the player is not authenticated to present the login form from game center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need. First, you need to check `error`. If it is set, the `viewController` will usually be nil and your code will incorrectly assume that you're logged in and communicating happily Game Center. You may appear logged in based on cached credentials, but in most cases, you won't actually be seeing current data from the server, you'll just have access to whatever data was last cached on the device.

Second, you have to present the viewController to the user if they're not logged in. Try this:

```
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"authenticateHandler");

    if (error)
    {
        //Examine the error. IOS may show you as "authenticated" based on
        //cached credentials, but you probably can't really communicate with
        //game center in any meaningful manner
    }
    else if (viewController != nil)
    {
        //You're not logged in, show the login viewController

        NSLog(@"viewController != nil");
        UIViewController *mainVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window] rootViewController];
        [mainVC presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:^
        {
              //the login view controller has been dismissed. Did it work?
              if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated)
              {
                  //Yes, Login worked. enable whatever comes next after successful login
              }
              else
              {
                  //No, login failed or was canceled.
              }  
        }];
    }
    else if (blockLocalPlayer.isAuthenticated)
    {
        NSLog(@"localPlayer already authenticated");
        //do some stuff
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"local player not authenticated");
        // not logged in
    }
};
```